# Как на node js в боте вк сделать обратную связь?

Tags: node.js

Как сделать так, чтобы когда пользователь вводил команду "Задать вопрос", бот отвечал "Напишите ваш вопрос", после чего пользователь вводит текст и бот отправляет мне в лс его сообщение?

Соц.Сеть : VK
Библиотека : node-vk-bot-api/easyvk/vk-io

Дайте пожалуйста код,не могу найти на GitHub(не реклама) ответ

Comment: Как сделать так, что бы люди сначала учили язык, а потом пытались писать ботов?

Comment: ну язык я более менее знаю,а саму библиотеку я изучаю..

Comment: Какую из? вы 3 библиотеки привели в пример...

Comment: как рази таки 3 и изучаю

Comment: Приведите свой код, что уже написали, объясните, что именно не получается. Здесь не готовые решения предоставляют, а помощь в решении вопроса. Самостоятельно попробуйте разобраться в теме, а здесь таргетированно спрашивайте.
Тем более, если Вы знаете язык "более ли менее" - то у вас с библиотекой не должно вопросов возникнуть в разборе, в общей функции.
Логика - получить сообщение от пользователя и, в зависимости от реализации, послать сообщение себе же... Через переменную, конструкцию .then(), да много способов реализовать